# dask jobqueue and scheduler_file

Tags: dask-distributed

For `dask_jobqueue`, is it OK to pass a `SGECluster` and `scheduler_file` when creating a `Client`?

Something like this:

`client = Client(cluster, scheduler_file='shirley.json')`

The reason is really, I want to my workers from `dask_jobqueue` to run on a specified IP/port. Thanks so much for the help.